# Trim spaces before database inserts

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a web application wherein i need to do insert data into database using hibernate for several functionalities.

However I forgot to trim spaces while inserting now i want that all future database inserts should be done after trimming the spaces. what is the best way to do so across all controller classes(I am using spring mvc).

I need to understand the approach.

Thanks

Comment: well you have many options, you can use triggers in the database for each table, or add a `@PrePersist`  and/or `@PreUpdate` method to your entities or even change the `setters` (i wouldnt do it anyway) in the entites, like: this.x = trim(x); https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/listeners.html

Answer (score 2):

Because you probably use setters anyway you could write your setters like this:

```
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = (name != null) ? name.trim() : null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at StringTrimmerEditor mentioned at [Spring Validation, Data Binding and Type Conversion](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html) and add to your controller code something like this:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, new StringTrimmerEditor(true));
}
```

Comment: somebody suggested AOP approach. But i dont know how exactly should i use it?